# Background mobile support

Tags: html, css, image, center

The code below works just fine on desktops. But on mobiles the images doesn't centralize correctly

```
<style>
    html, body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 4000px; /* just an example */
    }
</style>
<div style="
        background-image: url('img/bg1.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: contain;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 998;">
</div>
```

I want it fixed on the center of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work for you i guess.

```html
<style>
    html, body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100% !important; /* @nicfo advice, for working on mobiles */
    }
</style>
<div style="
        background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-size: contain;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 998;">
</div>
```

Comment: It is has the same issue of my code. If you increase the height of the page will not centralize on the view part of the screen, on devices.

Answer (score 1):

to stretch the image to fill the screen:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

to fill screen without stretching the image:

```
background-size: cover;
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: the first option will stretch the image. The second option will crop some parts of the image. I can't have any of this situations

Comment: oh sorry, i misunderstood. have you tried it with `height: 100%` at body?

Comment: It is a full screen ad, if i use `height: 100%` on body, it may cause some issues when the visitor close this ad.

Comment: well, the background's height is relative to the parent element (the body) so the image is actually centered, but it would fit a device with a 4000px screen. how could it cause issues when closing the ad though?